# Websocket server: Handle close event per session

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websocket

Is there a way to handle the server-side close event of a websocket per-session? This is how I currently implemented it:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/ws")
public class WebsocketServerEndpoint {
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        System.out.println("Websocket opened");
        CustomWebsocketHandler handler = new CustomWebsocketHandler(session); // see below
        // ...
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason reason) {
        System.out.println("Websocket closed. Reason: " + reason);
    }
}
```

But I want to wrap new `Session` instances inside a custom object. For messages, I can add the handler directly to the specific session via `addMessageHandler`. But how can I add a handler for the `onClose` event on that specific session?:

```
class CustomWebsocketHandler {
    public CustomWebsocketHandler(Session session) {
        session.addMessageHandler((MessageHandler.Whole<String>) this::handleMessage);
        // How to hook up close event to handleClose()?
    }

    private void handleMessage(String message) { /* ... */ }

    private void handleClose() { /* ... */ }
}
```

One idea I had was to track every session in the `WebsocketServerEndpoint` and their respective `CustomWebsocketHandler` instances, and go through them for every close-event, forwarding the event. However this is very cumbersome and feels error prone:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/ws")
public class WebsocketServerEndpoint {
    private List<Pair<Session, CustomWebsocketHandler>> sessions = new ArrayList<>();

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        // ...
        sessions.add(Pair.of(session, handler)); // not hashable I suppose
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason reason) {
        // ...
        for (Iterator<Pair<Session, CustomWebsocketHandler>> it = sessions.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            Pair<Session, CustomWebsocketHandler> pair = it.next();
            if (pair.getLeft() == session) {
                pair.getRight().handleClose();
                it.remove();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the client side of things this is easy, because each connection can use its own instance of a `ClientEndpoint`-annotated class:

```
webSocketContainer.connectToServer(endpointInstance, websocketURI);
```

Does something similar exist for the server side, or is it otherwise cleanly possible to handle the serverside `onClose` (and eventually also `onError`) event per session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, **a new instance of the `ServerEndpoint`-annotated class is created for each new client**. This behaviour is controlled by the [`ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator#getEndpointInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.html#getEndpointInstance-java.lang.Class-) method:

> The platform default implementation of this method returns a new endpoint instance per call, thereby ensuring that there is one endpoint instance per client, the default deployment cardinality.

This means that it's safe to store session-specific state in the `WebsocketServerEndpoint` class itself, without having to manually associate sessions with custom connection instances:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/ws")
public class WebsocketServerEndpoint {
    private CustomWebsocketHandler handler;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        handler = new CustomWebsocketHandler(session);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason reason) {
        handler.handleClose();
    }
}
```

At this point it might also be easier to just have the annotated class `WebsocketServerEndpoint` be that required `CustomWebsocketHandler` itself, as it has the same semantics: One instance per connection and handles websocket events.